# how to generate batch files in a loop in Python (not a loop in a batch file) with slightly changed parameters per iteration

Tags: linux, unix, sh, batch-processing, slurm

I am a researcher that needs to run files for a set of years on a SLURM system (high performance computing center). The available nodes for long compute times have a long queue. I have 42 years to run, and the only way to run them that gets my files processed quickly (due to the wait times, and that this is many GB of data, it takes time), is to submit them individually, one batch file per year, as jobs. I cannot include multiple years in a single batch file, or I have to wait a week in the queue to run my data due to the time I have to reserve per batch file. This is the fastest way my university's system lets me run my data.

To do this, I have 2 lines in my batch script that I have to change every time: the name of the job, and the last line which is the python script name plus a parameter being passed to it (the year)
like so: pythonscript.py 2020.

I would like to generate batch files with a python or other script I can run, where it loops over a list of years and just changes the job name to jobNameYEAR and changes the last line to pythonscript.py YEAR, writes that to a file jobNameYEAR.sl, then continues in a loop to output the next batch file. ...Even better if it can write the batch file and submit the job (sjob jobNameYEAR) before continuing in the loop, but I realize maybe this is asking too much. But separately...

Is there a way to submit jobs in a loop once these files are created? E.g. loop through the year list and submit sjob jobName2000.sl, sjob jobName2001.sl, sjob jobName2002.sl

I do **not** want a loop in the batch file changing the variable, this would mean reserving too many hours on the SLURM system for a single job. I want a loop outside of the batch file that generates multiple batch files I can submit as jobs.

Thank you for your help!

This is what one of my .sl files looks like, it works fine, I just want to generate these files in a loop so I can stop editing them by hand:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
# The -l above is required to get the full environment with modules
# Set the allocation to be charged for this job
# not required if you have set a default allocation
#SBATCH -A MYFOLDER
# The name of the job
#SBATCH -J jobNameYEAR
# 24 hour wall-clock time will be given to this job
#SBATCH -t 3:00:00
# Job partition
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=6
#SBATCH --mem=30GB
#SBATCH -p main
# load the anaconda module
ml PDC/21.11
ml Anaconda3/2021.05
conda activate myEnv
python pythonfilename.py YEAR
```

Comment: Do I understand right, that you want to create multiple copies if the script in the question where all occurrences of `YEAR` are replaced by a specific year from a set or range of years? Do you want to specify a range of years or a set of individual years e.g. one per line in a file? What file names do you want to have for the generated scripts? Please [edit] your question to provide this information.

Comment: I guess jobs must run in sequence and must not run in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

Create a script with the following content (let's call it `chainsubmit.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash

SCRIPT=${1?Usage: $0 script.slum arg1 arg2 ...}
shift
ARG=$1
ID=$(sbatch --job-name=jobName$ARG --parsable $SCRIPT $ARG)
shift
for ARG in "$@"; do
  ID=$(sbatch --job-name=jobName$ARG --parsable --dependency=afterok:${ID%%;*} $SCRIPT $ARG)
done
```

Then, adapt your script so that the last line

```
python pythonfilename.py YEAR
```

is replaced with

```
python pythonfilename.py $1
```

Finally submit all the jobs with

```
./chainsubmit.sh jobName.sl {2000..2004}
```

for instance for `YEAR` ranging from 2000 to 2004

Answer (score 0):

> … script I can run, where it loops over a list of years and just changes the job name to jobNameYEAR and changes the last line to pythonscript.py YEAR, writes that to a file jobNameYEAR.sl… submit the job (sjob jobNameYEAR) before continuing in the loop…

It can easily be done with a few shell commands and `sed`. Assume you have a template file `jobNameYEAR.sl` as shown, which *literally* contains `jobNameYEAR` and `YEAR` as the parameters. Then we can substitute `YEAR` with each given year in the loop, e. g.

```
seq 2000 2002|while read year
do  <jobNameYEAR.sl sed s/YEAR$/$year/ >jobName$year.sl
    sjob jobName$year.sl
done
```

If your years aren't in sequence, we can use e. g. `echo 1962 1965 1970` instead of `seq …`.

Other variants are on Linux also possible, like `for year in {2000..2002}` instead of `seq 2000 2002|while read year`, and using `envsubst` instead of `sed`.